# JNI callback to Java from c++ class crashing

Tags: java, android, c++, callback, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call a Java function from a C++ class using JNI on Android. I have searched and searched but haven't found my exact case. I can call methods in my c++ library from Java, but am having issues doing the reverse. I've messed with it for two days now and am wasting time, so could someone more knowledgable than I help me out?

Full goal: Preserve the JNIEnv OR just the JavaVM (to get and attach a valid JNIEnv later) passed to a native c++ JNI EXPORT call from Java for later use by a c++ class method (not a JNI EXPORT).

So, Java class method calls native c++ method, passing its JNIEnv* and jobject. Store those as static class members in a c++ class. Later, a method of that c++ class uses those static members to callback a Java method of the same class that originally passed its context or whatever.

I've tried using env->NewGlobalRef(someObj); but it's strange because that will make some future uses of the reference objects succeed, but some still fail.

Here's some code:

Java code:

```
//this is what I want to call from native code
public void something(String msg)
{
//do something with msg
}

public void somethingElse()
{
    callNative();
}

private native void callNatve();

//access native
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("someLib");
}
```

All of the above works fine, the c++ trying to do the same however, does not. (Note: I need the class in my native library as a class and not standalone static calls)

C++ code:
(Note: for simplicity here everything is public)

MyClass.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <jni.h>

class MyClass
{
    //ctor
    //dtor

    void someCall(std::string)

    static JNIEnv* envRef;
    static JavaVM* jvmRef;
    static jobject objRef;
};
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
MyClass.cpp

```
#include <MyClass.h>

//static members
MyClass:;:JNIEnv* envRef;
MyClass::JavaVM* jvmRef;
MyClass::jobject objRef;

//this is the method whose instructions are crashing
void MyClass::someCall(std::string msg)
{
     //works assuming i call env->NewGlobalRef(MyClass::objRef) or setup/reattach from jvm in exported call or here
     jstring passMsg = envRef->NewStringUTF(msg.c_str());

    clsRef = envRef->GetObjectClass(objRef);
    if(clsRef == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    //This doesn't cause crash, but if I call FindClass("where/is/MyClass"); it does... strange
    jmethodID id = envRef->GetMethodID(clsRef, "something", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if(id == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Crashes
    //envRef->CallVoidMethod(clsRef, id, passMsg);

    if(envRef->ExceptionCheck())
    {
        envRef->ExceptionDescribe();
    }

    //Also crashes
    //jvmRef->DetachCurrentThread();
}

//this works
extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_my_project_class_callNative(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
    {
        MyClass::objRef = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);
        MyClass::envRef = env;

        //tried both
        //MyClass::envRef->GetJavaVM(&MyClass::jvmRef);
        env->GetJavaVM(&MyClass::jvmRef);


        //Tried this
        /*
        int envStat = MyClass::jvmRef->GetEnv((void**)&MyClass::envRef, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
        if(envStat == JNI_EDETACHED)
        {
            //TODO: LOG
            //std::cout << "GetEnv: not attached" << std::endl;
            if(MyClass::jvmRef->AttachCurrentThread(&MyClass::envRef, NULL) != 0)
            {
                //TODO: LOG
                //std::cout << "Failed to attach" << std::endl;
            }
        }else if(envStat == JNI_OK)
        {
            //
        }else if(envStat == JNI_EVERSION)
        {
            //TODO: LOG
            //std::cout << "GetEnv: version not supported" << std::endl;
        }
        */

        //calling detachcurrentthread here crashes if set above

        MyClassObj.someCall(an std::string);
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different approaches but they all cause crashes. I do DeleteGlobalRef() too when I use it, but it crashes way before then.  Any insight is appreciated

**EDIT #1:**
As per Michael's suggestion, I've implemented the JNI_OnLoad function and have cached just the JavaVM* from there. Inside the MyClass::someCall(std::string) method I then use the JavaVM to get the JNIEnv, initialize a jclass object using env->FindClass and get the methodID for the something(String) java method, but attempting to callback to Java with CallVoidMethod results in a crash still.

OnLoad defined as extern "C" in MyClass.cpp:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void* reserved)
{
    MyClass::jvmRef = jvm;

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Updated MyClass::someCall definition:

```
void MyClass::someCall(std::string msg)
{
    //Get environment from cached jvm
    JNIEnv* env;
    jclass cls;

    int envStat = MyClass::jvmRef->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    bool attached = false;
    if(envStat == JNI_EDETACHED)
    {
        //TODO: LOG
        if(JavaInterface::jvmRef->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL) != 0)
        {
            //TODO: LOG
            // "Failed to attach"
            return;
        }else if(envStat == JNI_OK)
        {
            attached = true;
        }else if(envStat == JNI_EVERSION)
        {
            //TODO: LOG
            // "GetEnv: version not supported"
        }
    }

     cls = env->FindClass("package/location/project/JavaClass");
    if(cls == NULL)
    {
        //TODO: LOG
        return;
    }

    jmethodID id = env->GetMethodID(cls, "something", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if(id == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    jstring passMsg = env->NewStringUTF(msg.c_str());

    //Crashes
    env->CallVoidMethod(cls, id, passMsg);

    if(attached)
        jvmRef->DetachCurrentThread();
 }
```

Comment: You're not supposed to cache `JNIEnv` pointers. The `JavaVM` pointer is safe to cache, so you can do that e.g. in `JNI_OnLoad`. And then you use that `JavaVM*` to get a `JNIEnv*` using `GetEnv`/`AttachCurrentThread`.

Comment: Note that when you obtain the `JNIEnv*`, you need to keep track of whether or not the thread already was attached to the VM. Because you mustn't call `DetachCurrentThread` unless you previously called `AttachCurrentThread` on that thread while it was deatched.

Comment: Ok, I've implemented a super simple JNI_OnLoad() and cache the jvm in it. I can get the JNI_Env from that while inside MyClass::someCall(std::string msg), find the jclass fine with FindClass, and get the methodid, but CallVoidMethod still crashes.

Comment: In your updated `someCall` function you're doing `env->FindClass` before you've made sure that you actually have a valid `JNIEnv*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the error after the Edit #1 changes is that I was passing the wrong object to CallVoidMethod().  What I ended up doing, which works, is storing the jobject passed by callNative(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) as a static member of MyClass and passing it to CallVoidMethod instead of cls.

An earlier call:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_path_to_project_JavaClass_nativeCall(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    JavaInterface::objRef = env->NewGlobalRef(obj)
}
```

DeleteGlobalRef(objRef) is called elsewhere after it's no longer needed. Then, the only change was in the native "someCall" method:

```
void MyClass::someCall(std::string msg)
{
    //everything here is the same

    //Now either of these will work
    cls = env->FindClass("com/empsoftworks/andr3ds/NativeInterface");
//cls = env->GetObjectClass(objRef);

    //unchanged stuff

    //This is what fixed it
    env->CallVoidMethod(objRef, id, passMsg);
}
```

Comment: That won't work either in the long run. You can't store `jobjects` acoss JNI method invocations. You need a `GlobalRef`. You don't seem to have done much reading. I suggest you study the JNI reference. All of it.

Comment: That's what I said. You need to use a `GlobalRef`, otherwise it won't work in the long run.

Comment: Method IDs are safe to cache, so there's no point in looking up the method ID more than once (e.g. in `JNI_OnLoad`).